# Поломались vitest тесты, после того как я разделил проект на клиент/сервер и добавил несколько новых тайпскрипт конфигов

Tags: node.js, nextjs, vite

Изначальная структура проекта была:
|src (папка с файлами nestjs)
|vitest
|tsconfig.json

Я стал дружить его с next в итоге структура стала:
|src
|--client
|--pages
|--server
|--shared
|vitest
|tsconfig.json
|tsconfig.server.json

В проекте появился tsconfig.server.json

И клиент и сервер работают, как в связки друг с другом, так и по отдельности, но тесты поломались, потому что vitest-ам перестали нравится typescript декораторы. Стал ругаться на декоратор "@Module"
:Error:
× Expression expected

К тому же заглючил VSCode. Стал подсвечивать красным импорты и декораторы, хотя, повторюсь, все собирается и работает.

Файлы:

```
//package.json
{
  "name": "techies",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "yarn build:next && yarn build:nest",
    "build:next": "next build",
    "build:nest": "nest build --path ./tsconfig.server.json",
    "start": "node ./dist/server/main.js",
    "start:next": "next dev",
    "start:dev": "nest start --path ./tsconfig.server.json --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --path ./tsconfig.server.json --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "prisma:generate": "prisma generate",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "vitest run",
    "test:ui": "vitest --ui",
    "test:typecheck": "vitest typecheck",
    "test:watch": "vitest",
    "test:cov": "vitest run --coverage",
    "test:debug": "vitest --inspect-brk --inspect --logHeapUsage --threads=false",
    "test:e2e": "vitest run --config ./vitest.config.e2e.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@faker-js/faker": "^8.0.2",
    "@fastify/cookie": "^9.0.4",
    "@fastify/nextjs": "^10.0.1",
    "@fastify/secure-session": "^7.1.0",
    "@fastify/session": "^10.5.0",
    "@fastify/static": "^6.11.0",
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^3.1.1",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^10.1.1",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-fastify": "^10.2.5",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^7.1.11",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.3.0",
    "@swc/core": "^1.3.84",
    "@vitest/coverage-c8": "^0.33.0",
    "@vitest/coverage-v8": "^0.34.4",
    "@vitest/ui": "^0.34.4",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "c8": "^8.0.1",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "nest-next": "^10.1.0",
    "nestjs-zod": "^3.0.0",
    "next": "^14.0.4",
    "prisma": "^5.3.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "unplugin-swc": "^1.4.2",
    "vitest": "^0.34.4",
    "vitest-mock-extended": "^1.3.1",
    "zod": "^3.22.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.3.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.46",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.18",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^14.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}

//tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2021",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ],
      "@modules/*": [
        "./src/server/modules/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}

// tsconfig.server.json, vitest.server.json
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noEmit": false,
        "outDir": "./dist/server",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/server/**/*.ts",
        "./src/shared/**/*.ts",
        "./@types/**/*.d.ts"
    ]
}

//vitest.config.js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'url'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import swc from 'unplugin-swc'
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [swc.vite()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      '@modules': fileURLToPath(
        new URL('./src/server/modules', import.meta.url),
      ),
    },
  },
  test: {
    include: ['./vitest/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,mjs,cjs,ts,mts,cts,jsx,tsx}'],
  },
})
```

Есть предположение что править нужно конфиг тестов, а именно указать его новый tsconfig, но я не понимаю как это сделать.